# How to default to encryption of new home directories when using ldap

Tags: encryption, home-directory, ldap

When using `adduser`, one can pass `--encrypt-home` to encrypt the newly generated home directory. Supposedly, this can be made the default by correctly setting up `/etc/adduser.conf`.

However, for administering a series of computers that get their user data via ldap, the homes are created on the fly. Nevertheless, there is a need to enable encryption - particularly since the computers are used by multiple users. It doesn't really matter which encryption system (ecryptfs et al.), but there is no point in encrypting the entire partition as decryption should only happen when individual users are logging in. How can such a per-user encryption of the automatically created home directories be achieved when authenticating via ldap?